# Slick cannot change HikariCP connectionTimeout

Tags: scala, slick, hikaricp

I'm trying to change the `maximumPoolSize` and `connectionTimeout` parameters for HikariCP for my slick database, here is my settings inside of `application.conf`

```
testNet3DatabaseUrl {
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
  driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
  db {
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bitcoins-spv-node-testnet3"
    user="bitcoins-spv-node-admin"
    password=""
    queueSize=5000
    numThreads=8
  }
  connectionTimeout=3000
  maximumPoolSize=100
}
```

Now, when I try and use my database, I get an error saying  `Exception: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1000ms of waiting for a connection.` Why isn't the timeout being set to `3000ms` like I have specified in my `application.conf`?

Comment: how are you applying these settings in your app? Are you expecting these settings to be automatically applied since they are in ```application.conf```?

Comment: @Barry, yes it seems (from what I have read) you can set these settings inside of `application.conf` for Slick apps?

Comment: Not sure what versions of Play/Slick your on but what I saw with some of the most recent versions is that there are certain default  keys it is looking for and ways to customize those so you could use a config like you have but as far as I can tell out of box if you want it to automatically use your config your layout/keys in the config need to match their expecatations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a stupid mistake on my part, here is what the settings need to be:

```
testNet3DatabaseUrl {
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
  driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
  db {
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bitcoins-spv-node-testnet3"
    user="bitcoins-spv-node-admin"
    password=""
    queueSize=5000
    numThreads=8
    connectionTimeout=3000
    maximumPoolSize=100
  }
}
```

You can see how this is parsed here: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-hikaricp/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/hikaricp/HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala#L43-L55